# Running blocking code in separate executor is failing with coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor()

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

hi following is minimum viable example which is failing to run a blocking code in a separate
event loop, can someone please let me know how to fix issue where code is failing as
TypeError: coroutines cannot be used with run_in_executor()

```
import asyncio


class XYZ:

    def __init__(self, pool):
        self.pool = pool

    def _connect(self, router):
        return self.pool.connect(router)

    async def _call(self, router, procedure, *args, **kwargs):
        async with self._connect(router) as session:
            return await session.call(procedure, *args, **kwargs)

    ########this is blocking code##########
    def get_system_info(self,router ,system_name):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        return loop.run_in_executor(None, self._call, f'url')
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = XYZ('pool')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete( d.get_system_info('route','sysname'))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `_call` through `run_in_executor` when it's async and you can just await it? I.e. replace `return loop.run_in_executor(None, self._call, f'url')` with `return await self._call(f'url'))` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing because `loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args)¶` has a function as an argument not a coroutine. change  `aysnc def _call` to synchronous i.e `def _call`, and make appropriate changes inside it. An option for that would be  to convert the session as a `task` and use `run_until_complete`in `_call` function

Comment: `_call` cannot be synchronous in the code as shown because it uses async constructs like `await` and `async with`. As far as I can tell without the rest of the context, the OP doesn't need `run_in_executor` in the first place and should just replace `return loop.run_in_executor(None, self._call, args...)` with `return await self._call(args...)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 The guy was saying code is just an example, I was saying a case where he needed to use an executor. Based on your reputation, I am no man to question u!! :)

Comment: Don't pay attention to my reputation, just the arguments, and you should question everyone. :) While it's true that the code in the question is just an example, I took it to be a _representative_ example, meaning that real code looks different, but also contains `await` and `async with`. If that is the case, my comment stands. If that is not the case and the OP's real code actually is synchronous, then your answer is quite correct. We can't be sure until the OP confirms one or the other.